# How to manipulate navbar bootstrap 4 collapse with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, menu, navbar

My menu is working perfectly. However when I click on the background to close the menu, the menu X keeps popping up. This is because when I click on the background he doesn't understand that it is now he is collapsed

Base:

```
<div ng-controller="mega_menu_controller">
    <nav class="main-menu navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-white shadow">
        <div class="container container-lg-fluid">
            <a class="main-menu__logo navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="{{ site.url }}"><span
                        class="icon-logo"></span></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed p-0 mb-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarsMenu" aria-controls="navbarsMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" ng-click="toggle_menu(4)" >
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse main-menu__links w-100" id="navbarsMenu">
                {# MENU DESKTOP #}
                <ul class="nav nav-pills mx-auto desktop">
                    <!-- Artigos -->
                    <li class="dropdown menu-large nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center"
                           ng-click="toggle_menu(1)" ng-class="{'active' : menu[1]}">Artigos
                            de Poupança <span class="icon-arrow-tip-down"></span></a>
                    </li>
```

AngularJs Code:

```
app.controller('mega_menu_controller', ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.menu = [];

    $scope.display_background = false;

    $scope.toggle_menu = function (i) {
        $scope.menu.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (index !== i)
                $scope.menu[index] = false;
        });

        if (i !== -1) {
            $scope.menu[i] = !$scope.menu[i];
            $scope.display_background = $scope.menu[i];
        } else
            $scope.display_background = false;
    }

}]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'background' when you say that you click on background? can you include complete code that replicates the issue, that'll make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
<div class="background-full position-fixed bottom-0 right-0 left-0 d-none" style="z-index:1029;"
     ng-class="{'d-block d-lg-none animated fadeIn faster': display_background && menu[4]}"
     ng-click="toggle_menu(-1)" data-toggle="collapse"
     data-target="#navbarsMenu"  >
</div>
```